# How can I do an indexOf() in Lotus Notes Formula language (@ commands)?

Tags: string, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I can't find this anywhere in the Domino Designer help. It seems so straightforward!

All I need to do is find the position of a character in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited) Please see the answer from charles ross instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437044/11293

My less efficient method is below.

---

If you really need the character position though you could do this:

```
REM {
    S  Source string
    F  Character to find
    R  Location of character in string or 0
};

S := "My string";
F := "t";
LEN_S := @Length(S);
R := 0;

@For(I := 1; I < LEN_S; I := I + 1;
    @If(@Middle(S; I; 1) = F;
        @Do(R := I; I := LEN_S);
        @Nothing
    )
);
```

Comment: There are more efficient answers below. The answer given by Charles Ross looks the best to me.

Answer (score 4):

You could use @Left or @Leftback. I think in this case they work the same.

```
src:= {your field value to search};
char:= {your target character};
indexof:= @Length(@Left(src;char))
```

Answer (score 1):

searchResult:=@Left(SearchString;"C");
indexOf:=@If(searchResult="";0;@Length(searchResult));
indexOf

Answer (score -1):

@Length(src) - @Length(@ReplaceSubstring(src;srch;""))

Comment: The result of this will be a count of characters in the string that match the search. It will not provide the position of a character within the string.